# Create two dataframes from two dataframes based on multiindex in one dataframe and columns in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I m not sure if this has been answered before. But my requirement is that 
I have a dataframe like this:

`df1:`

```
         A  B
I1 I2

x11 x12  a11 b11
x12 x22  a21 b21
```

Note that this has multiindex of `[I1, I2]` and columns `[A, B]`

and then another dataframe like this:

`df2:`

```
    I1   I2
  0  x11  x12
  1  y11  y12
```

This has columns `[I1, I2]` which is the same as multiindex of `df1`.

Now what I would like to create is two dataframes like below:

`df3` which has rows for which the index in `df1` matches to that of column values in `df2`

```
A  B
a11 b11
```

`df4` with the remaining i.e.

```
A  B
a21 b21
```

I know how to do this using `iterrows()` but it is not efficient. Looking for a vectorized solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `reset_index` with `merge`

```
df3=df1.reset_index().merge(df2).set_index(['I1','I2'])
df4=df1.drop(df3.index)
```

Or

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)
df3=df1.reindex(idx).dropna()
df4=df1.drop(df3.index)
```

Comment: Thank you, I m going to check on this. Also on another note, with the first approach I get a multiindex of type `[I1, [I21, I22]]` , how can I flatten this like `[I1, I21]`, `[I1, I22]` ?

Comment: @check itertools product ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to record another way of doing it, posting this:

I could `set_index` on `df2` with `[I1, I2]` and then do a `isin` like:

`is_index_there = df1.index.isin(df2.set_index([I1, I2]).index)`

and then use that to create separate dfs like :

`df3 = df1.loc[is_index_there == True]` and

`df4 = df2.loc[is_index_there == False]`